# how to create a the launch file xml

Tags: ros, roslaunch, tutorial, xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i follow the tutorials to 2.3 The launch file .the tutorials just tell us to :"Now let's create a launch file called turtlemimic.launch and paste the following: "but it doesn't tell us how to create a launch file .so ,i really don't know where to past the scripts it provides :

```
<launch>

  <group ns="turtlesim1">
    <node pkg="turtlesim" name="sim" type="turtlesim_node"/>
  </group>

  <group ns="turtlesim2">
    <node pkg="turtlesim" name="sim" type="turtlesim_node"/>
  </group>

  <node pkg="turtlesim" name="mimic" type="mimic">
    <remap from="input" to="turtlesim1/turtle1"/>
    <remap from="output" to="turtlesim2/turtle1"/>
  </node>

</launch>
```

so ,could any can tell me how to create a launch file and where to paste the scripts .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258407/how-to-create-a-the-launch-file-xml/) by [zpzsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/29785/zpzsky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-04-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [agbj](https://answers.ros.org/users/29369/agbj/) on 2017-04-01**:
Typically the .launch files stay inside a catkin package in the folder launch. Not sure if this is the answer that you pretend. If not please be more explicit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A launch file is a text file whose name ends in `.launch`; you can create them with your favorite text editor or IDE.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nullspace](https://answers.ros.org/users/57539/nullspace/) on 2020-09-10**:
but sir how will you make it as xml file as well as launch file ,will you add .xml or .launch as extension

**Comment by [a_shaman](https://answers.ros.org/users/116404/a_shaman/) on 2022-09-03**:
save the file with .launch extension